# MySQL batch and join: is it possible using SQL file injection?

Tags: mysql

Here's a sample of a table I have:

```
mysql> select * from table_a where description='Auto';
+----+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| id | idparent | description | description_url |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| 11 |     NULL | Auto        | NULL            | 
| 74 |       73 | Auto        | NULL            | 
+----+----------+-------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now I insert into another table another record and remember its last inserted id:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (description) values ('Myvalue');
set @lt=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Now I have into `@lt` the value.
I could do this (and it works):

```
INSERT INTO table_a_link_b (id_a, id_b) VALUES (11, @lt);
INSERT INTO table_a_link_b (id_a, id_b) VALUES (74, @lt);
```

Now what follows doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO table_a_link_b (id_a, id_b) VALUES
    ( (SELECT id FROM table_a where description='Auto') , @lt);
```

So I tried to put it into a variable:

```
mysql> set @t=(select id from table_a where description='Auto');
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

It doesn't work. Is there a way I could do it *without making a Php batch file* and stay **pure** SQL?

Comment: Confused by your use of `batch` and `injection`.  Could you clarify?

Comment: batch = file where there are orders. SQL batch = file where there are SQL orders. Injection = **`mysql -u user -ppassword databasename < batch.file.sql`**. I know I know this is not the kind of "SQL injection" that you may have thought ;)... but hey this is injection straight into database isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_a_link_b (id_a, id_b)
SELECT id,@lt FROM table_a where description='Auto';
```

Comment: Here's my query that worked, thanks to you man! **`insert into metier_categorie (SELECT @lt,id from categorie2 where description='Automobile');`** Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
INSERT INTO table_a_link_b (id_a, id_b) 
  SELECT id, max(table_b.id) FROM table_a 
    join table_b on table_a.description = table_b.description
   where table_a.description='Auto' group by table_a.id;
```